# Gst good plugins installed but - no element "autovideosink"

Tags: gstreamer

I am following the GStreamer basic tutorials.  Good plugins installed. Tutorial 2 (which includes building a pipeline in C with autovideosink)  works fine - so autovideosink element is obviously present - where it should be.  However - Tutorial 10 (GStreamer Tools) where I'm trying to use autovideosink from a command line does not work.   (This is an Ubuntu 16.04 environment)

```
# any attempt to use autovideosink says no element
$ gst-inspect-1.0 autovideosink
No such element or plugin 'autovideosink'

# good plugins installed
$ dpkg -l | grep gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:amd64
ii  gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:amd64             1.8.3-1ubuntu0.4                             amd64        GStreamer plugins from the "good" set

# shared object file is present
$ locate libgstautodetect.so /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstautodetect.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstautodetect.so
```

Searching Stackoverflow and other places, I see people asked the same question but the question went unanswered.

Answer (score 3):

this is a path problem.
see this link:
https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/design/missing-plugins.html
To see the path you need (in my case autovideo sink is in the libgstautodetect.so)

```
locate libgstautodetect.so /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstautodetect.so
```

should see:  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstautodetect.so
so then add that to the gstreamer path

```
export GST_PLUGIN_SYSTEM_PATH_1_0=$GST_PLUGIN_SYSTEM_PATH_1_0:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0
echo $GST_PLUGIN_SYSTEM_PATH_1_0
```

you should see:   :/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0
and now it works:

```
gst-inspect-1.0 autovideosink
```